# Cloning Existing Mints

Tags: spl-token, mint, local-cluster

I am developing a program that takes an existing mint as payment for services, is it possible to not only clone this Mint but then mint the tokens to accounts in my localnet testing?

Example:

Clone $USDC Token Mint to my solana-local-validator, Mint USDC to a fresh testing account to use in various tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out! (thanks to discord searching)

Process:

1. Clone the Mint Account you want to use:

```
solana account EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v --output json-compact --output-file usdc.json
```

2. Generate a keypair to use as your new mint authority, use this mint authority in all your tests, I hardcoded the secret key in the test file for simplicity.

```
# secretKey is hardcoded in the tests file
MINT_AUTHORITY="8XbgRBz8pHzCBy4mwgr4ViDhJWFc35cd7E5oo3t5FvY";
```

3. Replace mint authority with new one in the account data:

```
python3 -c "import base64;import base58;import json;usdc = json.load(open('usdc.json'));data = bytearray(base64.b64decode(usdc['account']['data'][0]));data[4:4+32] = base58.b58decode('${MINT_AUTHORITY}');print(base64.b64encode(data));usdc['account']['data'][0] = base64.b64encode(data).decode('utf8');json.dump(usdc, open('usdc-mock.json', 'w'))"
```

4. Upload account when you start your validator via Anchor

```
# mock $UDSC Mint with our own Mint Authority
[[test.validator.account]]
address = "EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v"
filename = "usdc-mock.json"
```

Now you can mint freely