# How to generate ATA?

Tags: web3.js, spl-token

I'm trying to create a new ATA owned by a program.

Here is my code :

```
var ata_program = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
    pg.connection,
    pg.wallet.keypair,
    MINT_USDC,
    pg.program.programId,
    true
);
```

But I get TokenAccountNotFoundError.

Do you have any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you share the repo, for more info.

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure you will get that error if you provide an incorrect mint address. You might be providing an incorrect mint address for the cluster you are on. Here are the addresses for USDC on Mainnet and Devnet:

| Network | USDC Key |
| --- | --- |
| Mainnet | `EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v` |
| Devnet | `4zMMC9srt5Ri5X14GAgXhaHii3GnPAEERYPJgZJDncDU` |

If you are working on localhost, you will have to clone the USDC account to your local validator before you can use it. [Here's a post](https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/2968/121) explaining how to do that.

Also, I don't think this is responsible for your error, but I do not suspect your intent is to pass `true` your final argument. Check out [Solana Cookbook](https://solanacookbook.com/references/accounts.html#generate-a-pda) for more info on PDAs.

Answer (score 0):

This is the function definition.

```
export async function getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
    connection: Connection,
    payer: Signer,
    mint: PublicKey,
    owner: PublicKey,
    allowOwnerOffCurve = false,
    commitment?: Commitment,
    confirmOptions?: ConfirmOptions,
    programId = TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    associatedTokenProgramId = ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
): Promise<Account>;
```

The fourth argument `allowOwnerOffCurve` tells the library if the owner is a PDA or not, you are passing true means that the owner is a PDA, but your programId is `onCurve`, hence it won't be able to get an associated token account for that owner

Change the true to false to get ATA of the program, if you intend to get ATA of a PDA, then change the owner to be a PDA, not a programId.